# Swagger Codegen - C# interfaces created for OneOf not implemented

Tags: c#, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen

I'm using Swagger Codegen to generate the C# files to allow me to interact with the API [here](https://digital.nhs.uk/developer/api-catalogue/electronic-prescription-service-fhir) ([raw](https://digital.nhs.uk/restapi/oas/324177)).

I'm using version 3.0.54 of the code generator, and ran it with:

```
java -jar .\swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i https://digital.nhs.uk/restapi/oas/324177 -l csharp
```

The generator is creating an interface to represent the items that could be populated in the `oneOf` sections, such as:

[image: Screenshot of OAS]

[image: Screenshot of generated Entry property]

[image: Screenshot of OneOfR4PrepareBodyEntryItems interface]

Unfortunately, this interface has no implementations, so I cannot create a valid request. The generator doesn't even appear to have created any of the classes that I would expect to implement this interface. I would (perhaps naively) assume that a class called `MedicationRequest` would be created that implements the `OneOfR4PrepareBodyEntryItems` interface. The closest I get is a class called `CreateMedicationRequestResource`, but this doesn't implement the interface, and isn't even referenced anywhere else in the project.

Strangely, the `OneOfR4PrepareBodyEntryItems` interface created is not prefixed with I, though the generator was configured to prefix with I.

Have I misconfigured something? Am I using the codegen tool incorrectly? Is the OAS not well-structured?

Comment: Please do not post images of code, but include the actual code itself. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 1):

Rather than fighting with a tool that is struggling to generate the required C# code, I would try another tooling option, as they will all differ in how they handle OpenAPI support for polymorphism (oneOf and anyOf).

- NSwag - https://www.nuget.org/packages/NSwag.AspNetCore
- Swashbuckle- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore
- Kiota - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OpenApi.Kiota
- Refit - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Refitter